# Wrong order of query, message (Product added successfully)

Tags: php

Is there a way to remove the product added successfully message after adding a wrong item

E.G. first add item, then add photo, if I add anything other than jpg or png. It will not add the item, the error message you will get is (Photo not added. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!) after that is (Product added successfully!).

PHP CODE

```
<?php
    include('session.php');

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
    $supplier=$_POST['supplier'];
    $qty=$_POST['qty'];


    if($qty == 0){
echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Quantity cannot be 0')
window.location.href='product.php';</script>";
exit;
}

    if($price == 0){
echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Price cannot be 0')
window.location.href='product.php';</script>";
exit;
}
    $fileInfo = PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

    if (empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])){
        $location="";
    }
    else{
        if ($fileInfo['extension'] == "jpg" OR $fileInfo['extension'] == "png") {
            $newFilename = $fileInfo['filename'] . "_" . time() . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $newFilename);
            $location = "upload/" . $newFilename;
        }




        else{
            $location="";
            ?>
                <script>
                    window.alert('Photo not added. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!');
                </script>
            <?php
        }
    }

    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into product (product_name,categoryid,product_price,product_qty,photo, supplierid) values ('$name','$category','$price','$qty','$location', '$supplier')");
    $pid=mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into inventory (userid, action, productid, quantity, inventory_date) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', 'Add Product', '$pid', '$qty', NOW())");

    ?>
        <script>
            window.alert('Product added successfully!');
            window.history.back();
        </script>
    <?php
?>
```

Thanks Guys!

Comment: There are lot of problems with the above code. Start by learning why do we use `mysqli_*` and how do we use `mysqli_*`. Also you should avoid mixing of php and js. You can echo a js using php but it does not mean you have to do it.

Comment: Your query is open to injection attacks.  Please use mysqli's prepared statements with placeholders every time you use user-supplied data in your queries.  If you don't, you and/or your users may be victimized.

Comment: @mickmackusa , as of know i am just practicing , i dont plan on releasing this

Comment: I recommend that you always practice best practices.  Because efficient coders copy-paste their pre-existing code blocks "that work".  Do yourself a favor and always do the right thing.  Furthermore, you will positively influence other developers when you post "good code" to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    include('session.php');

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
    $supplier=$_POST['supplier'];
    $qty=$_POST['qty'];


    if($qty == 0){
echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Quantity cannot be 0');
window.location.href='product.php';</script>";
exit;
}

    if($price == 0){
echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Price cannot be 0');
window.location.href='product.php';</script>";
exit;
}
    $fileInfo = PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

    if (empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])){
        $location="";
    }
    else{
        if ($fileInfo['extension'] == "jpg" OR $fileInfo['extension'] == "png") {
            $newFilename = $fileInfo['filename'] . "_" . time() . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $newFilename);
            $location = "upload/" . $newFilename;
        }




        else{
            $location="";
            ?>
                <script>
                    window.alert('Photo not added. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!');
window.location.href='product.php';
                </script>
            <?php
            exit;
        }
    }

    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into product (product_name,categoryid,product_price,product_qty,photo, supplierid) values ('$name','$category','$price','$qty','$location', '$supplier')");
    $pid=mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into inventory (userid, action, productid, quantity, inventory_date) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', 'Add Product', '$pid', '$qty', NOW())");

    ?>
        <script>
            window.alert('Product added successfully!');
            window.history.back();
        </script>
    <?php
?>
```

simply add exit; after the                     window.alert('Photo not added. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!');

Comment: it did work but after that , it just reloaded to a white screen. It did not redirect to my php file. I did add this ( <script type="text/javascript">location.href = 'http://localhost/inventory30/pos_inventory/admin/addproduct.php';</script>) but still reloaded to a white screen

Comment: did you got the "Photo not added. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!' message

Comment: try to add window.location.href='product.php'; after the                     window.alert('Photo not added. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!');

Comment: you have some missing semi colon, try again now.

Comment: sir I tried the window.location it works now thank you very much

Comment: great. nice to know

Answer (score 0):

what i understand according to that you want's to validate image when you upload any image. you can use code , i think this will help you

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
}else{
// check image is empty or not
if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])){
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        $location = $target_dir.$target_file;
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        $location = "";
    }
}
}
```